# how to update an object when several other related objects get created

Tags: python, django

I have to add a progress_level field to my User model that shows where does this user stand at the moment so I added a field to the user model like this:

```
progress_level = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, choices=USER_PROGRESS_LEVELS)
```

I want this field to automatically update itself whenever an action gets done by the user. for instance, if the user completes their contact info and document info and submit their forms, the progress level should change to [1][0]. I really dont know how to do this but I created a signal like this:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='progress_change')
def progress(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    user = instance
    if DocumentInfo.objects.filter(user=user).exists() and ContactInfo.objects.filter(user=user).exists():
        user.progress_level = USER_PROGRESS_LEVELS[1][0]
```

it works fine but it activates only if I save the User model. how can I prevent that? how can I activate this signal whenever that statement is true? if is there a better way to do this please help me. I really dont know if signals are the right way to do this.
these are my models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    isPreRegistered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=13)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, default=None)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, default=None)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, choices=GENDER)
    progress_level = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, choices=USER_PROGRESS_LEVELS)
    isDetailViewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class DocumentInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    certificate = models.FileField(upload_to="documents")
    id_card = models.FileField(upload_to="documents")
    service_certificate = models.FileField(upload_to="documents")
    educational_certificate = models.FileField(upload_to="documents")
```

############EDIT##############
I added this save method to my user model. it works but I want this to update user model without saving it. what I mean is I want it to check the document and contact info models and if they exist, update that progress_level. I have to save the user model manually from admin page for this to happen. how can I fix it

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.documentinfo and self.contactinfo:
        self.progress_level = USER_PROGRESS_LEVELS[4][0]
    return super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about updating the model save method?

**models.py**

```py
class User(...):

    ...
    document_info = models.OneToOneField(DocumentInfo, ...)
    contact_info = models.OneToOneField(ContactInfo, ...)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if self.document_info and self.contact_info:
            self.progress_level = USER_PROGRESS_LEVELS[1][0]

        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: but how? if I add this statement to the save method, how can the user model recognise other models? the contact info and document info are related to the user model with a foreign key relation.

Comment: there are many ways to achieve your goal - the method you proposed in your question in my opinion is the best - if you dont want to use your approach you can override the save methods (or use signals) of the `ContactInfo` and `DocumentInfo` models that check for the appropriate conditions but this may be more cumbersome to manage than your current approach.

Comment: EDIT: assuming the User model has a foreign key relation to a `DocumentInfo` and `ContactInfo` you can shorten your code as I have done in my answer - perhaps you can  share your models.py code ?

Comment: I added my models please check them out. this wont work because I connected these models to the user not the other way. there is not document_info or contact_info field in the user model

Comment: So - to be sure - one user can have many documents and many contact infos?

Comment: no, let me change it to one to one field.

Comment: I would recommend putting the relation on the `User` model - this will make your code a bit simpler, see my edited answer. You can also apply this logic in the `pre_save` signal as you have it now. The other advantage of this approach is that you won't incur any extra SQL joins when checking if these fields are populated on the user.

Answer (score 0):

You want change the progress_level value where you add some document or complete contact ... how about you do this in save or update method on document model or contact model ... contact or document model that related with specific user have save or update method can effect "progress_level" value on user model trough user instance.
you can fetch user instance from document model on save method (cause you have foreign key) and check the process has been don ... increase "progress_level" by user instance.
if you don't know how in code let me know to explain that with sample code

Comment: I dont know how to update a field in a model by making a save method in another model. I edited relations to one to one relation. could you help me with the code

Comment: I put sample code in new post ... hope be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your models shaped like this:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    progress_level = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=0) 
    // some other field 

class DocumentInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    // some other field
```

You set serializer for document like this:

```
class DocumentInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer(many=False, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = DocumentInfo
        fields = ('id', 'user', /* some other fields */)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

Now in DocumentInfo model you should code save method like this:

```
class DocumentInfoManager(models.Manager):
    
    def create(self, user, **kwargs):
        user_obj = User.objects.get(id=user.id)            
        user_obj.progress_level = 1 // set progress_level here 
        user.save()                 // user instance update here

        document_obj = DocumentInfo(user=user, **kwargs)
        document_obj.save()

        return document_obj 

class DocumentInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    // some other field
    objects = DocumentInfoManager() // this line is necessary
```

You define id in User model.
Note that in model is not necessary define id (primary_key) field with increment argument ... django create id for each model automatically